# AWS ALB -> ECS - register target that is not publicly accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS web server cluster (Fargate) that sits in front of an ALB with autoscaling and sticky sessions enabled (using our own application cookie)

Question is, is it possible to manually start a new ECS task that registers a target which does not receive any new traffic from the load balancer UNLESS it has the sticky session cookie set (or could be some secret http header).

The use-case is that it allows us to test a new deployment privately before it is released to the world, we could route requests to the container using our session cookie.

Comment: why not just add a http header rule in the alb ?

Comment: do you mean to forward onto a different target group based on a http header value? that would mean the test server is operating in a different ECS cluster